# Adding a row at the end of a table when the rows are added dynamically and performing calculations on a column that should appear in the row

Tags: jquery, html

**I would like to have a subtotal row at the end of the table that has the sum of the "total" column (the fourth column of the table.)**

problem: the row is not being appended correctly. the "subtot" row is only being added at the end of the table after every  other row being added

problem: the calculation part is all messed up

problem: when I put in jsfidle I can't change the select box but I was able to do it locally.

I think I went down a terrible route trying to program this and Im sure you have a much better way to get it done.

I tried to do something like the code below because the forth column is being updated every time the select box is changed and I need that value when it is changed so I could get the correct total in the "subtot" row.

I used  .text()-0 because I thought I was having problems with the values in the fourth column being  a number.

FYI. this code is a lil different than the one i am showing in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/A7zYm/1/)

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var $fourth = $('.row td:nth-child(4)').text()-0;
   if(isNaN($fourth)) {
  //just to test if number
    $('.row td:nth-child(4)').css("color", "green")
   }
    // alert($.type($fourth))
  var row = $('.row td:nth-child(4)').parent()
    $('.row td:nth-child(4)').each(function(){
        qnty = $(this).siblings('.select').val()-0;
        alert(qnty);
        total =  parseFloat($(this).text()-0) * qnty;
       $('tr.subtot td:nth-child(4)').html(total)
    })
});
```

The adding of the subtot row is below. This is the best I could do right now with my knowledge.
I figure there is something wrong with the way I'm using . remove ()

```
   if($(".subtot").length && $(".subtot:not(:last-child)")){
        $(".subtot").remove();
    }else{
    $("table:nth-last-child(1)").append('<tr class = "subtot"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>test</td></tr>')

    }
```

I've just started learning jquery and If you help me figure this out, it will help me with my learning process and I would appreciate that alot.